# Google chrome app writing files to the app folder

Tags: filesystems, google-chrome-app

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr documents access to
a file in the source code by a user of an installed chrome app.
ie xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL('/config_resources/config.json')
It works for the app I'm developing.
Where is the root folder for such "local" urls?
Can a user of my chrome app save a file to this folder? How?

Answer (score 0):

The extension folder is not writable or accessible to the user. If it is acceptable for the files to be not accessible outside your app, you can write  files using the [sandboxed filesystem api](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

You can also access the files in your package using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch) or 
[chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry)